# GSuite : Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method

Tags: google-apps, google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace

Hi I'm trying to develop an for GSuite admin which enables to migrate their google drive data to another cloud service. But in the process of authentication i'm getting the below error.

```
{
  "error": "unauthorized_client",
  "error_description": "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method."
}
```

Below are the api's that are enabled in developer console.
1. Admin SDK
2. Contacts API
3. G Mail API
4. Calendar API
5. Drive API

Please guide me if done anything wrong in creating an app.

Comment: are you using a service account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing what i missed here is Authorizing my service account client ID with the GSUITE admin.

And I have been trying to generate access_token for the expired domain of mine.

After clearing all these i have to success in generating and getting user data.

This solution worked for me. I hope it works for you tooo....

Thank you community.